# How to link the Python 3.7.0 interpreter to Pycharm on Mac

Tags: pycharm, python-3.7

I just recently upgraded to Python 3.7.0 on my Mac via a Homebrew installation.  Unfortunately this process resulted in my prior 3.6.5 installation being removed and as a result Pycharm no longer links to the interpreter.  I went into the Pycharm menu in the following fashion `Pycharm >> Preferences >> Project Interpreter` and tried to add the new path link to the 3.7.0 installation, which was at `Users/myname/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.7.0/bin/python3.7` and I get a message `Environment location directory is not empty` which indicates I am not linking to the proper item, but if this is not it I am not sure where I should be linking to.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to add the 3.7 installation as a *virtual* environment, rather than a "system" installation of Python. Try this:

1. Open the Project Interpreter settings (Cmd+A, search for Project Interpreter)
2. Click the settings "gear" icon next to the Project Interpreter dropdown
3. Click Add
4. In the left-hand sidebar of the "Add Python Interpreter" dialog that appears, click "System Interpreter" (rather than the default of "Virtualenv Environment").
5. Use the ". . ." button to locate your installation.

Comment: Thanks man. Worked a treat on MacOS 12.6 using a custom python installation in userland.